# Is Multicast broken for Android 2.0.1 (currently on the DROID) or am I missing something?

Tags: java, android, multicast, datagram

This code works perfectly in Ubuntu, Windows, and Mac OS X. It also works fine with a Nexus One running Android 2.1.1.

I start sending and listening multicast datagrams, and all the computers and the Nexus One will see each other perfectly. Then I **run the same code on a Droid** (Firmware 2.0.1), and **everybody will get the packets sent by the Droid, but the droid will listen only to its own packets**.

This is the `run()` method of a thread that's constantly listening on a Multicast group for incoming packets sent to that group.

I'm running my tests on a local network where I have multicast support enabled in the router.
My goal is to have devices meet each other as they come online by broadcasting packages to a multicast group.

```
public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65535];
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

    try {
        MulticastSocket ms = new MulticastSocket(_port);
        ms.setNetworkInterface(_ni); //non loopback network interface passed
        ms.joinGroup(_ia); //the multicast address, currently 224.0.1.16
        Log.v(TAG,"Joined Group " + _ia);

        while (true) {
            ms.receive(dp);
            String s = new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());
            Log.v(TAG,"Received Package on "+ _ni.getName() +": " + s);
            Message m = new Message();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("event", "Listener ("+_ni.getName()+"): \"" + s + "\"");
            m.setData(b);
            dispatchMessage(m); //send to ui thread
        }
    } catch (SocketException se) {
        System.err.println(se);
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        System.err.println(ie);
    }
}
```

This is the code that sends the Multicast Datagram out of every valid network interface available (that's not the loopback interface).

```
public void sendPing() {
    MulticastSocket ms = null;
    try {
        ms = new MulticastSocket(_port);
        ms.setTimeToLive(TTL_GLOBAL);

        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = getMulticastNonLoopbackNetworkInterfaces();
        for (NetworkInterface iface : interfaces) {
            //skip loopback
            if (iface.getName().equals("lo"))
                continue;
            ms.setNetworkInterface(iface);
            _buffer = ("FW-"+ _name +" PING ("+iface.getName()+":"+iface.getInetAddresses().nextElement()+")").getBytes();
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(_buffer, _buffer.length,_ia,_port);
            ms.send(dp);
            Log.v(TAG,"Announcer: Sent packet - " + new String(_buffer) + " from " + iface.getDisplayName());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Update (April 2nd 2010)**
I found a way to have the Droid's network interface to communicate using Multicast: [WifiManager.MulticastLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html).

```
MulticastLock _wifiMulticastLock = ((WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).createMulticastLock("multicastLockNameHere");
_wifiMulticastLock.acquire();
```

Then when you're done...

```
if (_wifiMulticastLock != null && _wifiMulticastLock.isHeld())
    _wifiMulticastLock.release();
```

After I did this, the Droid started sending and receiving UDP Datagrams on a Multicast group.

**Update Jul-6-2010**

Per request, here's my current code, the next method exists on an abstract class that can be used for both Broadcast and Multicast receivers.

```
public void run() {
    onInit();
    try {
        byte[] data = new byte[65535];
        while (isProcessing()) {
            try {
                DatagramPacket receivedDatagram = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                _socket.receive(receivedDatagram);
                onDatagramReceived(receivedDatagram);
                data = new byte[65535]; // This pattern is for saving memory allocation.
            } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
                if (!isProcessing())
                    break;
            }
        } // while

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        onStop();
        _socket.close();
        _socket.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Your extending classes should implement `onInit()` and `onDatagramReceived()`

For a **Multicast** receiver, `onInit()` **looks something** like this:

```
_socket = new MulticastSocket(PORT_MULTICAST);
InetAddress groupAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(MULTICAST_GROUP_ADDRESS); 
InetAddress groupInetAddress = FrostWireUtils.fastResolveAddress(groupAddress); //reflection hack to not resolve ips
try {
    _socket.setSoTimeout(500);
    _socket.setTimeToLive(MULTICAST_TTL_GLOBAL);
    _socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    _socket.setNetworkInterface(
        WifiUtils.getWifiNetworkInterface());
    _socket.joinGroup(groupInetAddress);
    WifiUtils.lockMulticast();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to receive Multicast packets on my Nexus-One (firmware 2.1.1).
I used the above code, but had no luck so far.
Can you please attach your complete source so I can compare it with mine? Thanks,
Eyal

Comment: Eya, I've added an update, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented another test, this time using UDP **Broadcast**.
It works.

**Conclusion:** To the extent of my knowledge Motorola Droid phones on firmware 2.0.1 don't support multicast, but you can always use regular DatagramPackets on the broadcast address.

Comment: See the Update (April 2nd 2010) on this thread.

I've managed to get the Droid to communicate over Multicast using firmware 2.0.1 by aqcquiring a Multicast Lock.

"WifiManager.MulticastLock

Allows an application to receive Wifi Multicast packets. Normally the Wifi stack filters out packets not explicitly addressed to this device. Acquring a MulticastLock will cause the stack to receive packets addressed to multicast addresses. Processing these extra packets can cause a noticable battery drain and should be disabled when not needed. "